# Is this rewriting of the metric tensor possible or not?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

The metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric, meaning that $g_{\mu\nu}$ = $g_{\nu\mu} $ for every special $\mu$ and $\nu$ in [0,3].
That sums up to $g_{\mu\nu}$ having 10 degrees of freedom.

$g_{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor *field*, meaning that every point in four-dimensional spacetime possesses an own tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$.

Now, I wonder whether it's possible to rewrite the tensor field of $g_{\mu\nu}$ as such, that at every single point consists of a  <s>metric</s>   tensor of the form where all $g_{0i} = g_{i0} =0 $ for $i\neq 0$. This construction would *also* possess exactly 10 degrees of freedom per point.

The aim would be to allow for a simple calculation of the determinant of $g_{\mu\nu} $.

Is it possible (allowed) to rewrite the metric tensor field to a (not "metric") tensor field in that way?

Comment: May be useful https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/721265/

Comment: *This construction would also possess exactly 10 degrees of freedom per point.* You’ve miscounted. The nonzero components are still symmetric.

Comment: @Ghoster why are the nonzero components still symmetric?

Comment: As you yourself said, the metric tensor is symmetric. It doesn’t stop being symmetric just because you’d like to impose some additional conditions.

Comment: This amounts to choosing coordinates where the [shift vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism#Overview) is zero everywhere. That should generically be possible.

Comment: @Ghoster I should then sacrifice the symmetry for allowing this reordering: in the second tensor $g_{ij}$ and $g_{ji}$ are independent from each other for i, j in [1,3].

Comment: Then it’s not a metric tensor of GR. GR (and Riemannian grometry in general) offers no possible way to distinguish $g_{ij}$ from $g_{ji}$.

Comment: That's okay for me (that I can't call the second object "metric tensor" anymore). :-) It's only a name. It has very much to do with the metric tensor as it can be calculated _directly_ from the original metric tensor. - - - The whole construction seems to me similar to approaching an arbitrary function f(x) with pieces of tangents. Here, we've got pieces of points with six arms of independent lengths (6 dof) and 3 independent angles between (x, y), (y, z) and (z, x) (3 dof) and one velocity of time $g_{00}$ at each point. In sum, 10 dof.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. In a neighborhood of every given point one can  finds local coordinates $x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3$ where the metric satisfies $g_{i0}=0$. It is sufficient to choose a   smooth spacelike hypersurface $\Sigma$ (co-dimesion 1 spacelike embedded submanifold) through $p$. Next one considers the geodesics normal to  $\Sigma$ with initial unit vector at $\Sigma$. In a suffiently small neighborhood of $p$ a coordinate system made of

- the 3 spatial coordinates on $\Sigma$ of the point where each geodesic meets $\Sigma$ and
- the affine parameter along the geodesic as the $0$-th coordinate

has the required property.

In these coordinates $g_{0k}=0$ for $k=1,2,3$ and also $g_{00} = -1$.
The degrees of freedom, at the end of the construction,  are in fact $6$: the independent components of the symmetric matrix  $[g_{ij}]$ for $i,j=1,2,3$.

The point is that this coordinate system is only local and it is possible to prove that it is necessarily local (after a certain time lapse some geodesics meet).
A physical proof of this fact can be found on the Landau-Lifshits textbook on Relativity.

Comment: That's not what OP means, if I understand correctly. They want a non-symmetric tensor with $g_{0k} = 0$, which has 10 degrees of freedom.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's a nice answer but not what I meant. In this answer it's a projection on a hyperplane.

Comment: I see, but I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could always make up a matrix

$$\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
g_{00} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & g_{11} & g_{12} & g_{13} \\
0 & g_{01} & g_{22} & g_{23} \\
0 & g_{02} & g_{03} & g_{33}
\end{pmatrix},$$

I guess. This satisfies $\tilde{g}_{0i} = \tilde{g}_{i0} = 0$ and contains all 10 components of the metric tensor. But not only is its determinant not equal to the determinant of $g_{\mu\nu}$, this is not even a tensor.

And it can't be a tensor no matter how you rearrange it, because the condition $\tilde{g}_{0i} = \tilde{g}_{i0} = 0$ is not coordinate independent. It might be true in one coordinate system, but it won't be true in others.

And finally, even if it was somehow possible to construct this simpler tensor, it wouldn't simplify the calculation of the determinant. It can't: since the determinant of $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$ is a simpler formula than that of $g_{\mu\nu}$, its components have to be more complicated in order that they have the same determinant. There's no free lunch: the value of the determinant is what it is, no matter how you rearrange the components.

Comment: Hm. The determinant of $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$ at every point is $g_{00} \cdot $ det ($g_{ij} $). That's what makes it so interesting. Could we demand det ($\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$)!= det($g_{\mu\nu} $) and use that to calculate $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: You still can't have a tensor with $\tilde{g}_{0i} = 0$. But ignoring that, what is the point of all this? You can define whatever you want, no one's going to stop you. But what are the goals? What is it supposed to be good for?

Comment: Why I can't have a tensor with $\tilde{g}_{0i} =0$?

Comment: You can't have a tensor with $\tilde{g}_{0i} = 0$ *in all coordinate systems*. The tensor transformation law implies that, in general, if these components are zero in one coordinate system they won't stay zero when you change coordinates.

Comment: Okay, I get a special $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$ from a special $g_{\mu\nu} $. If we change the coordinates, $g_{\mu\nu}$ will change accordingly to $g'_{\mu\nu}$ as it is a tensor. Then, it should be possible to calculate a new corresponding $\tilde{g'}_{\mu\nu}$. If there is a map from $g_{\mu\nu} $ to $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$ then it should be possible to find a $\tilde{g'}_{\mu\nu}$ in every coordinates, isn't it?

Comment: "not only is its determinant not equal to the determinant of gμν, this is not even a tensor" sounds like being a tensor is simpler than having the same det, but I think it's simpler to have the same determinant because that's just a mapping to a scalar.

Comment: Strongly related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/788632/what-consequences-would-it-have-to-postulate-zero-shift-vectors-in-gr

Comment: How about "postulating" the shift vector to be zero in every coordinate system. Would it then be possible to calculate a $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu} $ which has the same determinant as $g_{\mu\nu} **and** is a tensor in this realm?