# What consequences would it have to postulate zero shift vectors in GR?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, free-fall

The shift vector is a part of the metric tensor in General Relativity (GR). It's $g_{0i}$ with $i$ in $[1,3]$.

This post is related to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/788282/) question. There, I ask whether a changing of coordinates is possible where the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ changes to $\tilde{g} _{\mu\nu}$ (see below) with $\tilde{g}_{0i}$ =0 while making *all* $\tilde{g}_{ij}$ independent (giving up the symmetry). The number of degrees of freedom stays the same (10). However, the new $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$ isn't a *tensor* in spacetime manifold, because if one changes the coordinates the shift vector possibly becomes something different than zero.

Now, I'm wondering why and how the shift vector can be different from zero at all.

For the coordinate system of an arbitrary observer on earth (me), is the shift vector zero or not zero?
How about an observer moving in free fall?
How about an observer on a planet which is much more compact than the earth?

What would be the consequences if we  postulated that the shift vector in every coordinate system we chose *has* to be zero?
As I understand it, this postulate would only restrict the coordinate system - not the degrees of freedom of the physical system. Right?

(Is it probably the case of free fall with shift vector = 0? No acceleration of the coordinate system? Or probably Droste coordinates, field-free observer? )

$$\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
g_{00} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & g_{11} & g_{12} & g_{13} \\
0 & g_{21} & g_{22} & g_{23} \\
0 & g_{31} & g_{32} & g_{33}
\end{pmatrix},$$

Addendum: Is $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}$ necessarily symmetric if it is a valid tensor or not?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are very much confused about how GR works. The compactness of a spherical mass has nothing to do with the metric tensor shape or with the coordinates.

Now first of all  $\tilde{g}_{\mu \nu}$ is clearly always a tensor$^1$: tensors ar COVARIANT with coordinate changes, not invariant.
And yes, since it is a metric tensor, it is always symmetric.

It is not always possible to take the transformation $g\rightarrow\tilde{g}$ where $\tilde{g}$ is the tensor you defined above. To be able to do such a transformation, you need a starting metric which allows it.

Now to the shift vector: when you subdivide a 4D manifold with the 3+1 formalism (the formalism in which the shift vector originates) you have that your 3D spacelike hypersurfaces are Lie dragged along the flow of the time vector which is a coordinate/parameter.

This vector field subdivides in:
$$\vec{\partial_t} = N\vec{m} + \vec{\beta}$$
Where $\vec{m}$ is the normal vector and $\vec{\beta} = g_{0i}$ is the shift vector.

Now to say that the shift vector is zero means that the coordinate time $t$ has always a gradient vector orthogonal to the spacelike hypersurfaces. It is not always possible: if your spacetime is, for example, non stationary or non static, like binary mergers, this is obviosly not true, so you cant have a zero shift vector.
In Schwartzschild black hole instead you can foliate spacetime in time-orthogonal hypersurfaces, so you can have a zero shift vector.

Since the shift vector is not a tensor you cannot impose it to be zero in every coordinate system. $g_{0i}$ cannot be always set to zero since it is PART OF A TENSOR and not a tensor. If you postulate that it is always zero, you broke the theory of General Relativity.

In spacetimes that admit a particular type of observers, called Eulerian, you can specify a frame where the shift vector is always zero: note that not every geometry admits such an observer.

The statement that the number of degrees of freedom is not modified by the choice of the shift vector is true. The number of degrees of freedom is wrong tho: GR has $16 - 6 - 4 - 4 = 2$ degrees of freedom.
You start from the 16 elements of the metric and subtract 6 due to symmetry. Then remove 4 due to the diffeomorphism invariance and then remove the 4 constraints coming from $\nabla_\mu G^{\mu\nu}=0$. You are finally left with only 2 physical degrees of freedom.

Before going to the ADM formalism of general relativity (to which the shif vector belongs) i strongly suggest you to fortify your understanding of more basic concepts of GR otherwise you will encounter troubles in the advanced formalism.

---

$^1$ by that i am referring only to the tensor components, the object that we are working with. The full tensor, $g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ is clearly invariant since it has no indices. But we are talking about components and i will refer to those as tensors in the answer

Comment: "tensors ar COVARIANT with coordinate changes, not invariant" Absolutely wrong. Tensors are by definition independent of choice of basis. Only the tensor *components* change (contravariantly or covariantly) with basis.

Comment: Why the number the dof reduce due to diffeomorphism invariance is 4? The Jacobi matrix which describes the diffeomorphism has again 10 dof.

Comment: How can I see whether the Eulerian observer is admitted or not? (How can I see it by looking at the metric tensor? Couldn't a non-zero shift vector always come from a strange choice of coordinates?)

Comment: Why does $\nabla_\mu G^{\mu\nu}=0$ (which is the conservation of energy and momentum) reduce the dof by 4?

Comment: @MartyMcFly 1) GR is a gauge theory, the gauge invariance (here diffeomorphism) kills some degrees of freedom (here 4)

Comment: 2) is not simple to understand wheter the spacetime admits an Eulerian observer. You can have a non-zero shift vector with a strange coordinate choice, but in this case you can change them to remove it. Not all metrics allow you to remove it by a coordinate change tho

Comment: 3) $\nabla_\mu G^{\mu \nu}$ are a set of 4 equations which relates the components of your metric tensor, so that 4 of the degrees of freedom are now killed by the constraints imposed by the conservation law. This is not the conservation law for energy and momentum, is a property of a manifold (an Einstein manifold) which in principle has nothing to do with energy and momentum. Is a property of geometry always true even in differential geometry which has nothing to do with physics

Comment: @VincentThacker i know that, but the OP seems already confused about tensor components, i did not wanted to add more complications to the answer. I'll edit the post tho

Comment: "1) GR is a gauge theory, the gauge invariance (here diffeomorphism) kills some degrees of freedom (here 4)" The question is: Why exactly 4 dof? 4 basis vectors have 4 components each - there are 16 dofs that describe a diffeomorphism

Comment: "The full tensor, $g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ is clearly invariant since it has no indices." Does "no indices" mean that it's only a scalar field????

Comment: No, a diffeomorphism is described by a single vector, not a basis. A diffeomorphism is the choice of a coordinate grid, and in 4D you can only choose 4 coordinates, hence it has 4 degrees. No, $g_{\mu \nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ is not a scalar field, its a 2-form field. And it is invariant since the metric components and the basis covectors counter-transforms. I suggest you again to take a closer lecture to some basic GR book, i see that you are very very confused about the nature of the theory (confusing basis vectors and coordinates or tensors and scalars)

Comment: I can suggest you a couple of good books on the subject